# Does Yoneda preserve the subobject classifier, if it exists?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category that has a subobject classifier $\Omega$ (I do not require $\mathcal{C}$ to be a topos).

Does the Yoneda embedding of $\mathcal{C}$ to the presheaf topos on $\mathcal{C}$ preserve the subobject classifier?

Comment: Let $\mathcal{E}$ be so that $\mathrm{Sub}(1)$ is not a complete lattice. Compare $Sub(1)$ and $\hom(1, \Omega)$ in both categories.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{E}$? Is it $\mathcal{C}$ in my notation?

Comment: Yes, $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{C}$. I somehow didn't notice what letter you used.

Comment: @hurkyl I see, it is not preserved, thanks. However, is there a classification of the categories that have this property? E.g. is $\mathbf{Sub}(1)$ being a complete lattice a necessary condition? When $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of finite sets there is preservation, for example...